# How can I display text differently from how it is actually stored?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown, conceal

I am making a custom syntax partially based on Markdown. I want to display links differently from how they are stored in the file. For example, `[About me](about.md)` in the file should be displayed as `About me` in Vim. This is well-supported by Vim's conceal feature. However, I want `[](about.md)` in the file to be displayed as `About me` in Vim, where `About me` comes from the file being linked to (`about.md`). Contents of `about.md`:

```
title: About me
date: 2020-01-23

My name is...
```

I want the `title` field of `about.md` to be displayed instead of `[](about.md)`. Any ideas on how I can do this in Vim?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Remember that Vim is a text editor.

Comment: Even if it were possible, it wouldn't be advisable to do it. If you are editing a file you need to see exactly what it contains, because the edits you make will be governed by what you see.